# data augmentation error in python: TypeError: pic should be PIL Image or ndarray. Got <class 'torch.Tensor'>

Tags: python

I am trying to perform data augmentation in python and I am getting an error. My goal is to apply augmentation on the training dataset(not on the test). For this, I have a flag (named augment = False) that is set to False by default. I have set it to 'True' for the Train dataset. The path '/content/data/img' contains images in '.jpg' format. Please have a look at the code:

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see you using the augument parameter. Secondly, you shouldn't apply `to_tensor_transform` if you applied transforms since your transforms already convert the image to tensor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see you using the augument parameter. Secondly, you shouldn't apply to_tensor_transform if you applied transforms since your transforms already convert the image to tensor.

```
class LesionDataset(Dataset):
 def __init__(self, img_dir, labels_fname, augment=False):
     
     self.img_dir = img_dir
     self.augument = augument
     self.labels_fname = pd.read_csv(labels_fname)
   
 def __len__(self):
       return len(self.labels_fname)

 def __getitem__(self, idx):
 
       image_id = self.labels_fname.iloc[idx,0]
       image = Image.open(os.path.join(self.img_dir, image_id +'.jpg')).convert("RGB")
       
       labels = self.labels_fname.drop(['image'], axis = 1)
       labels = np.array(labels)
       labels = np.argmax(labels, axis = 1)
       label = labels[idx]
       if self.augument:
           image = train_transforms(image)
       else:
           image = to_tensor_transform(image)
       return image, label
```

Comment: okay. Thanks, Mihail. It works now but it shows another error for the training loop. `RuntimeError: mat1 dim 1 must match mat2 dim 0`

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67739615/runtimeerror-mat1-dim-1-must-match-mat2-dim-0-with-addition-of-data-augmentatio)